# Knife tool not cutting anything

Tags: knife-tool

My knife tool doesn't work, here is a gif of it.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to edit mode, press <kbd>A</kbd>, then press <kbd>M</kbd> and merge by distance. It should fix it!

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue by having overlapping geometry? I tried but the knife tool wouldn't behave as on the OP's GIF. Sure, it may not cut properly without pressing Z to cut through, but it does follow the mouse cursor.